# Error: oracle.security.crypto.asn1.ASN1FormatException: Got tag 0 instead of 16

Tags: java, oracle, certificate, x509certificate

Currently I am working with Oracle identity federation 10.1.4.0.1. I am facing one problem while exporting certificate to Certificate Validation, the error I am getting after importing certificate at console is:

ERROR - oracle.security.crypto.asn1.ASN1FormatException: Got tag 0 instead of 16.
Write failed: Broken pipe

But It doesn't displaying any error in webapge after exporting certificate.

Did you have any idea what this exception meant?

Any help in this regard really appreciated.

Thanks,
Narendra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASN.1 is a encoding format. X.509 certificates are encoded in ASN.1 format. An ASN.1 tag is an identifier which describes a section of an ASN.1 encoding. Getting the 0 instead of the 16 probably means that your data (certificate) is corrupt. Try parsing the certificate with openssl.

```
openssl asn1parse -in mycert.pem
```

If your certificate parses ok, then it may be an error in your local key store or an network error, either one preventing you from finding the singing certificate. Try validating your certificate with openssl.

```
openssl verify mycert.pem
```

If all the certificates are ok, then there is an error in your code.